# display uploaded image in admin grid in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, adminform, image-upload

I want to display an uploaded image in admin grid which is uploaded through a form

```
<column name="image"> 
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array"> 
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">image</item>
    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Image</item>
    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Comment: can you please add your grid code ? so I will guide you proper way

Comment: <column name="image">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">image</item>
     <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Image</item>
     <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
      <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
      </item>
     </item>
    </item>
   </argument>
  </column>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add below code in your ui_component file

```
<!-- Image Column -->
        <column name="image" class="Module\Vendor\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Thumbnail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
                   <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                   <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                   <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                   <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                   <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">300</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Now in your `/app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Thumbnail.php`
add following code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\MOdule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;

class Thumbnail extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    const NAME = 'thumbnail';

    const ALT_FIELD = 'name';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $editUrl;

    private $_objectManager = null;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $filename = 'pub/media/customizationimages/'.$item['customization_attachment'];
                $item[$fieldName . '_src'] = $this->urlBuilder->getBaseUrl().$filename;
                $item[$fieldName . '_alt'] = $this->getAlt($item) ?: $filename;
                $item[$fieldName . '_link'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                    'adminhtml/module/edit',
                    ['id' => $item['id']]);
                $item[$fieldName . '_orig_src'] = $this->urlBuilder->getBaseUrl().$filename;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    protected function getAlt($row)
    {
        $altField = $this->getData('config/altField') ?: self::ALT_FIELD;
        return isset($row[$altField]) ? $row[$altField] : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: image come in thumbnail.php

Comment: can you add full error here ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: image in Thumbnail.php on line 51

Comment: please debug your code before line no 51 and share me what you get in debug array?

Comment: i have debug whole code there is error in that line only

Comment: inline 51 image is written where it is declare

Comment: check with this before line no 51. print_r($item); exit;

Comment: no value is coming in array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89650/discussion-between-aasim-goriya-and-ashish-ramchandani).

Answer (score 2):

In admin grid, suppose you are calling your image and it is showing image url

Now all you have to do is call a callback function in it

```
$this->addColumn(
    'image',
    [
        'header' => __('Image'),
        'index' => 'image',
        'type' => 'image',
        'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_image'),
    ]
);
```

In your callback function return image frame

```
public function callback_image($value)
{
    if (empty($value)){
        return '';
    }
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $mediaUrl = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    $width = 150;
    return "<img src='" . $mediaUrl . $value . "' width='" . $width . "'/>";
}
```

That would be all, I personally used this code before

Comment: in my admin grid image name is showing through that I want to display an image@Shoaib Munir

Comment: Before image name, you need to populate whole image URL in function `callback_image`

Comment: but i want to display particular image with image name in admin grid

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your grid?

Comment: there is no option available for screenshot upload

Comment: What is image name that you are getting?

Comment: for ex: screenshot.png that is the name of image

Comment: Now in `callback_image` function `$mediaUrl = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);` is the line where you can get media url
Now you need to add you directory in image source like this:
`$mediaUrl."YourDirectory/Another_Directory".$value`

Comment: where to add this code

Comment: and in `addColumn` you will use image name index like: `'index' => 'image_name_etc',`

Comment: @AshishRamchandani in call backback_image function. See my answer, I think I have already give you so much detail in it

Comment: $this->addColumn(
    'image',
    [
        'header' => __('Image'),
        'index' => 'image',
        'type' => 'image',
        'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_image'),
    ]
); where to add this code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89616/discussion-between-ashish-ramchandani-and-shoaib-munir).